# Images "intersection" using ImageMagick

Tags: linux, image-processing, imagemagick

How can I get "intersection" of multiple images involving color fuzziness like in the below example (blue denotes common pixels):

[image: fooar]

[image: fooar]

A [image: A]
B [image: B]
C [image: C]
D [image: D]
E [image: E]

Is it possible with ImageMagick cli or some other tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below command worked for me:

```
convert A B -compose difference -composite -fuzz 30% -fill blue -opaque black -fuzz 30% -fill white -opaque white D
```